# How do I split a string into separate components to parse into a DateTime?

Tags: ruby

I have a string that looks like:

```
20130518134721
yyyymmddhhmmss
```

This is basically the time of day. Knowing the format of the string, and knowing that the year is padded to four digits and all others are padded to two digits, how can I split this string so that I can extract specific information such as the month, or the hour?

Comment: While the question is a duplicate of "possible duplicate", the underlying need is completely different, and isn't a duplicate at all, but a question about how to parse date strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.strptime` to convert the `String` to a `DateTime` object. You can do something like:

```
date = DateTime.strptime("20130518134721", "%Y%m%d%H%M%s") → datetime
```

After that, you can access to different methods of `Date` object in ruby like `hour` or `mon`.

```
date.hour               
#=> 13
date.mon
#=> 5
```

Also, remember to `require 'date'` to use `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'
d = DateTime.parse("20130518134721")
p d.hour #=> 13
p d.mon #=> 5
p d.min #=> 47
p d.day #=> 18
p d.year #=> 2013
```

Comment: `parse` is useful, and pretty smart, but also gets fooled. If you know the format it's better to use `strptime`, which doesn't waste time trying to sort-out which pattern to use. I'd recommend looking at [Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org) if you want to rely on parsing freeform strings into dates/times.

Answer (score 1):

Dates are best handled by the Date class as others have demonstrated. Splitting up strings into substrings with fixed width in general can be done with the `unpack` method:

```
year, month, day, hour, min, sec = "20130518134721".unpack("A4A2A2A2A2A2")
puts day #=> 18
```